# IUrlHelper Url.IsLocalUrl(url) does not work with route-names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to test if route-names are local or not but the only way I know to validate this is through `Url.IsLocalUrl(string url)` but it returns `false` when I pass route-name: for example I have decorated one of my action methods with `[HttpGet("list-employment-post", Name = "list_employment_post")]` so this `Url.IsLocalUrl("list_employment_post")` fails.

Comment: What is your string url like? If your string url is something like:`"/list-employment-post"`,it is local url.But if your string url is something like:`"https://localhost:44309/list-employment-post"`,it is non-local.Refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper.islocalurl?view=aspnetcore-2.2#examples

Comment: Hi, thank you for being kind enough to respond, I have tried the string template `/list-employment-post` but that did not work but I was using route names for example `list_employment_post`, which should be translated to an absolute path and `Url.IsLocal` supports absolute urls.

Comment: How did you use `Url.IsLocalUrl(string url)`?Actually,if your url string is absolute url or use virtual paths,it would return true.I test by using `var flag = Url.IsLocalUrl("/list_employment_post");`It returns true.

Comment: @Rena thank you for your kind response, I was using it without the _/_ forward-slash just the route-name `Url.IsLocalUrl("list_employment_post")`. I will try this out.

Comment: @Rena thank you it worked as it should.

Answer (score 1):

If your string url is something like:`"/list-employment-post"`,it is local url.But if your string url is something like:`"https://localhost:44309/list-employment-post"`,it is non-local.

You could check url like below:

```
var flag = Url.IsLocalUrl("/list_employment_post");
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper.islocalurl?view=aspnetcore-2.2#examples